# Is this finite state machine correct?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, formal-grammar

I have to build a f.s.m. for the language $((00)(0+1)^*)+((0+1)^*(110))$ is this correct?

[image: Here's what I did]

Answer (score 2):

This automaton (from the second version of your question):

[image: Here's what I did]

is correct.

As for this automaton (from the first version of your question):

[image: Here's what I did]

it is not correct, because it accepts $\mathtt{1010}$, which is not in your language. If you are using a nondeterministic automaton anyway, why don't you just split it into either the first expression of the union (which you got right) and the second (which you almost got right, but made a mistake in connecting the two).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

**Edit:** Updated the answer to match the changed question.

Comment: The exercise doesn't specify the type of automaton to use, I just updated the photo with a new version of the exercise, is that correct now?

Comment: @Bleeeaa: It is bad style to substantially change a question in a way that an existing answer no longer fits it. I just wasted time trying to figure out how to generate "1010" with the automaton you drew, before noticing your comment and realizing that this is **not** the automaton the answer refers to. "Thank you" for wasting my time! Note that in the worst case, I could have downvoted the answer for being "wrong" without ever realizing that you changed the question after the fact, giving dltdarek an undeserved negative reputation.

Comment: @celtschk Thank you $\ddot\smile$